Flask swagger UI is not created
I don't know, what i do wrong, but this is my code. I'm trying to generate swagger documentation for the API, but when I'm running app, I receive result like in the picture.What I am missing here ? Any help would be great
(https://i.sstatic.net/yrcZLPs0.png)
from importlib import metadata
from flask import Flask
from marshmallow import Schema, fields
from apispec import APISpec
from apispec.ext.marshmallow import MarshmallowPlugin
from apispec_webframeworks.flask import FlaskPlugin
from flask import Blueprint, current_app, json, request
from flask_swagger_ui import get_swaggerui_blueprint
import werkzeug
werkzeug.cached_property = werkzeug.utils.cached_property
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
from flask_restx import Namespace, api


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api()

examples =  {1:{'id': 1,
             'amount': 2,
             'firm': 'Lenovo',
             'country': 'Japan',
             'presense': True
          },2:{
              'id': 2,
              'amount': 1,
              'firm': 'Linu',
              'country':'Russia',
              'presense': True
          }
        }


class InputSchema(Schema):
   id = fields.Int(required=True, example=1)

class OutputSchema(Schema):
   id = fields.Int(required=True, example=1)
   amount = fields.Int()
   firm = fields.Str(required= False)
   country = fields.Str(required= True)
   presense = fields.Boolean()

class ErrorSchema(Schema):
    code_error = fields.Int(required=True, example=404)
    description = fields.Str(required= False)


def create_tags(spec):
   """ Создаем теги.

   :param spec: объект APISpec для сохранения тегов
   """
   tags = [{'name': 'Laptops'}]

   for tag in tags:
       print(f"Добавляем тег: {tag['name']}")
       spec.tag(tag)

blueprint_list = Blueprint(name="list", import_name=__name__)

@blueprint_list.route('/list')

def lap_list():
    """
       ---
       get:
         summary: Возвращает список ноутбуков
         parameters:
         responses:
           '200':
             description: Список ноутбуков
             content:
               application/json:
                 schema: OutputSchema
         tags:
           - Laptops
       """
    return examples,
    status=200,
    mimetype='application/json'

def load_docstrings(spec, app):
    """ Загружаем описание API.

   :param spec: объект APISpec, куда загружаем описание функций
   :param app: экземпляр Flask приложения, откуда берем описание функций
   """
    for fn_name in app.view_functions:
       if fn_name == 'static':
           continue
       print(f'Загружаем описание для функции: {fn_name}')
       view_fn = app.view_functions[fn_name]
       spec.path(view=view_fn)


def get_apispec(app):
   """ Формируем объект APISpec.

   :param app: объект Flask приложения
   """
   spec = APISpec(
       title="My App",
       version="1.0.0",
       openapi_version="3.0.3",
       plugins=[FlaskPlugin(), MarshmallowPlugin()],
   )
   spec.components.schema("Input", schema=InputSchema)
   spec.components.schema("Output", schema=OutputSchema)
   spec.components.schema("Error", schema=ErrorSchema)
   create_tags(spec)

   load_docstrings(spec, app)

   return spec
@app.route('/swagger')
def create_swagger_spec():
   return json.dumps(get_apispec(app).to_dict())


SWAGGER_URL = '/docs'
API_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/swagger'

swagger_ui_blueprint = get_swaggerui_blueprint(
   SWAGGER_URL,
   API_URL,
   config={
       'app_name': 'My App'
   }
)

app.register_blueprint(swagger_ui_blueprint)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port='5000', host='127.0.0.1')

I'm trying to run any examples with code from different web-sites, but I can't receive swagger documentation in UI format
